# Permissions to write files in the apache folder /var/www/html from PHP

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I have apache running on Ubuntu and I'm trying to write (copy an image) in the following folder:  `/var/www/html/images`

I'm trying to write it from HTML/PHP

```
 <?php
$uploaddir = '/var/www/html/images';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

And I get the following message:

The file is valid and was successfully uploaded.

Here is some more debugging info:

```
Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => Twitter.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpwNoxUG
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 4870
        )

)
```

So I'm assuming the code is working; I think the issue is that I don't have permission to write in the folder `/var/www/html/images` from PHP because I can manually drop a picture in there.

I checked the `error.log` file and there is no error registered

**Note:**

I already tried all the combinations of adding slashes to the path: `/var/www/html/images`, `/var/www/html/images/` etc and that's not the issue.

Comment: @Ron  I checked with ls -ld /var/www/html/images  and this is what I got:  drwxrwxr -x 2  samuel samuel 4096 Apr 4 15:12  /var/www/html/images   (samuel is my user I guess) but don't know who is the user that connects through PHP and HTML. As mentioned I can drop and image and copy it in the directory but not though the PHP file. Thank you so much

Comment: @Ron  Thanks again. I'm not seeing apache, this is what I see when running the command provided:  `samuel    9490  0.0  0.0  13692  2120 pts/1    R+   13:24   0:00 grep --color=auto httpd`